# How to pop a string from an array of strings in C without a segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to create a method to dynamically allocate an array of string values.  I have been able to successfully create the functions that will dynamically allocate strings to the vector, but am having problems with the function that will pop a string from the array.  The pop function works sometimes, but create segmentation faults others, typically when the popped index is smaller in size than the one that will fill its place.  Obviously this has to do with overlapping memory, but I thought that the method I am employing would fix the problem, and it is not.

```
typedef struct
{
    char **array;
    size_t active_length;
    size_t num_bytes;
}

int init_string_vector(String *vec) {
    char **ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed in file %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        free(ptr);
        return -1;
    }
    vec->num_bytes = 0;
    vec->active_length = 0;
    vec->array = ptr;
    return 1;
}

int push_string_scalar_vec(String *vec, char *value, size_t index) {
    // Allows a user to push a value to a specific index as long as it is in bounds
    if (index > vec->active_length) {
        fprintf(stderr, "String index out of range in file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    value = strdup(value);
    size_t length = strlen(value);
    const char *test = ((char *)value) + length;
    int cmp = strcmp(test, "\0");
    if (cmp != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "String in file %s on line %d does not have a null terminator\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    size_t size = sizeof(char *) * vec->num_bytes + length;
    char **resized = (char **)realloc(vec->array, size);
    if (resized == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        free(resized);
        vec->num_bytes -= length;
        return -1;
    }
    vec->array = resized;

    for (size_t i = vec->active_length + 1; i > index; i--) {
        vec->array[i] = vec->array[i-1];
    }
    vec->array[index] = value;
    vec->active_length += 1;
    vec->num_bytes += length;
    return 1;
}

void pop_string_scalar_vector(String *vec, size_t index) {
    size_t length = strlen(vec->array[index]);
    for (size_t i = index; i < vec->active_length - 1; i++) {
        vec->array[i] = vec->array[i + 1];
    }
    vec->num_bytes -= length;
    vec->array = (char **)realloc(vec->array, vec->num_bytes * sizeof(char));
    vec->active_length -= 1;
}

void free_string_vec(String *vec) {
    if (vec != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->active_length; i++) {
            free(vec->array[i]);
        }
        free(vec->array);
        vec->array = NULL;
        vec->active_length = 0;
        vec->num_bytes = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    String vec;
    init_string_vector(&vec);
    push_string_scalar_vector(&vec, "One", vec.active_length);
    push_string_scalar_vector(&vec, "Two", vec.active_length);
    push_string_scalar_vector(&vec, "Three", vec.active_length);
    push_string_scalar_vector(&vec, "Four", vec.active_length);

    // - This line values, but will work if I change the value
    //   from 2 to 3
    pop_string_scalar_vec(&vec, 2);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You're missing includes and it looks like part of the structure definition which I assume is `String;`.

Comment: pop & push_string_scalar_vec but you call them as _vector.

Comment: `strcmp(((char *)value) + strlen(value), "\0");` (condensed) makes *no sense* as a means to check for a null byte. `strlen` relies upon the null byte. If it is not there, you are already in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) land.

Comment: Why would you allocate the size of `array` to be the total number of bytes in its elements? `array` is an array of pointers.

Comment: Overly complicated... You seem to be muddling some count of the number of bytes with the index into the array of pointers.

Comment: If realloc fails there is no point in free'ing the NULL pointer.

Comment: The loop to make a space for the new value doesn't work.  It should not run at all if you append values.  Use memmove() instead.

Comment: Why do you think that the method you are employing would fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Added missing headers.
2. (main issue 1 of 2) Eliminated `num_bytes` as you are dealing with pointers.  You can add it back in again, if you want to track how much data is stored of course.  It should just not be part of any `realloc()` consideration though (as you `strdup()` your value).
3. Added the missing typedef name `String`.
4. `push_string_scalar_vec()`: Removed the `cmp` stuff to check for NULL.  You can't do it that way.  If you don't have a string then caller needs to tell you how many bytes are giving you.
5. (main issue 2 of 2) `push_string_scalar_vec()`:  The `for()` loop to make space is not correct.  Replaced it with a conditional `memmove()`.  As you append it's not being executed here unlike the for loop which was.
6. `pop_string_scalar_vec()`: return -1 on error.
7. `pop_string_scalar_vec()`: add index check
8. `pop_string_scalar_vec()`: handle `realloc()` failure.
9. `pop_string_scalar_vec()`: free the string (but see next).
10. (Not fixed) `pop_string_scalar_vec()` should presumable return the string being popped.
11. `main()`: Fixed the vec vs vector name mismatch.
12. `main()`: added call to `free_string_vec()`.
13. (Not fixed) Consider tracking capacity and have each call to `realloc()` do more than sizeof(char *) changes.  Say, if you need space increase capacity to `1.3 * active_length`.  Or maybe a 4k page at a time (sizeof(char *) * 512).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char **array;
    size_t active_length;
} String;

int init_string_vector(String *vec) {
    vec->array = NULL;
    vec->active_length = 0;
    return 1;
}

int push_string_scalar_vec(String *vec, char *value, size_t index) {
    if (index > vec->active_length) {
        fprintf(stderr, "String index out of range in file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    char **resized = realloc(vec->array, sizeof(*vec->array) * (vec->active_length + 1));
    if (!resized) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    value = strdup(value);
    vec->array = resized;
    if(index < vec->active_length) {
        memmove(vec->array+index+1, vec->array+index, sizeof(*vec->array) * (vec->active_length - index));
    }
    vec->array[index] = value;
    vec->active_length++;
    return 1;
}

int pop_string_scalar_vec(String *vec, size_t index) {
    if(index + 1 > vec->active_length) {
        fprintf(stderr, "index out or range at file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    char *value = vec->array[index];
    if(index + 1 < vec->active_length) {
        memmove(vec->array+index, vec->array+index+1, sizeof(*vec->array) * (vec->active_length - index - 1));
    }
    char **resized = realloc(vec->array, sizeof(*vec->array) * (vec->active_length - 1));
    if(!resized) {
        fprintf(stderr, "String index out of range in file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        memmove(vec->array+index+1, vec->array+index, sizeof(char *) * (vec->active_length - index - 1));
        vec->array[index] = value;
        return -1;
    }
    vec->array = resized;
    vec->active_length--;
    free(value);
    return 1;
}

void free_string_vec(String *vec) {
    if (!vec)
        return;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->active_length; i++) {
        free(vec->array[i]);
    }
    free(vec->array);
    vec->array = NULL;
    vec->active_length = 0;
}

int main() {
    String vec;
    init_string_vector(&vec);
    push_string_scalar_vec(&vec, "One", vec.active_length);
    push_string_scalar_vec(&vec, "Two", vec.active_length);
    push_string_scalar_vec(&vec, "Three", vec.active_length);
    push_string_scalar_vec(&vec, "Four", vec.active_length);
    pop_string_scalar_vec(&vec, 2);
    free_string_vec(&vec);
}
```

And here is the output from running your program through valgrind:

```
==800351== HEAP SUMMARY:
==800351==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==800351==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 123 bytes allocated
==800351== 
==800351== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```